# Compare to SQL Tables that share 1 Matching Value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, admin

I'm fairly new to SQL and Database Queries, I'm looking to compare two tables to get a value from table B where Table A matches the column in Table B to return this.

[image: Example TableA:]

[image: Example TableB]

I need to get the "id" from TableB where the "town" matches in both TableA and TableB.

Can someone help with a query for this?

Thanks,

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` the tables together.

Comment: Hello, As @GordonLinoff toldl you, you have to learn how to `JOIN` the tables. Please, review the [MySQL Join Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) or the [W3Schools Join Docs](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). I recommend you the first docs because are the official, the seconds are usefull to novices but less accurate.

Comment: I do not see matched towns in shown sample data.

Comment: The data shown isn't the entire table - One table contains 180k rows, whereas the other 1300. There are matching towns, just not visible.